# Transaction for user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, transactions

With the following code I would like to create a database user. For this I want to use the Active Record Transactions. Sadly my code doesn't work, so is somebody able to help me?

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction("CREATE USER " + @user.name + " IDENTIFIED BY "1234")
rescue => e
  puts e.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a chance to think about this, basically you need to change the database to the system one.
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
          :adapter  => "mysql2",
          :host     => "localhost",
          :username => "me",
          :password => "secret",
          :database => "activerecord"
        )

`:database` will be the name of the database that contains the `User` table.

Then you can wrap the `User` creation in a transaction, you would do it like this:

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      User.create({:name => "my_name"})
    end
```

The attributes used should match what you find in the system `User` table.

There are probably things you should do like closing connections and such before you do this, but that depends on where you are calling this from.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I think with User.create(...) it creates a normal user in a table. But I want creating a database user. Do I have to make an explicit model for that?

Comment: oh, you are right, I just misread the question.  So, I guess I don't quite understand why you need to do this via ActiveRecord?

Comment: I had a chance to think about this, basically you need to change the database to the system one.
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
          :adapter  => "mysql2",
          :host     => "localhost",
          :username => "me",
          :password => "secret",
          :database => "activerecord"
        )